# How to implement 'findelements' in Page Object Model using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, mstest

I am implementing findelements in POM using C# Selenium.

I have implemented below code but it does not work.

Page Object

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a")]
    public IList<IWebElement> propertyList1 { get; set; }
```

Accessing this in test method

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void test1pageObject()
    {
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, t);
        t.cli();
        t.cliEntervalueclickenter();


       IList<IWebElement> a= t.propertyList1;    //this code is not working. didn't returning any value.   
    }
```

I have checked normal selenium code `var ss = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a"));` by this code it is working fine.

Comment: Please provide more informations, how you are calling this object? How is your constructors?

Comment: PO contains Classes- created a Class lets say TC1 which contains initialization of webelements using FindsBy Annotations. 
Created Test Methods different folder where i am writing Test methods. lets say TM1 contains test case name test1pageObject() inside that i am creating object of  class TC1 & to work findsby annotation used Page Factory. Syntax for the same is PageFactory.InitElements(driver, ObjTC1); by that findsby annotation works. & by Object of the Class TC1 am getting WebElements & perform operation on it. 
We can use  constructor in TC1 but as of now i haven't used.